# Log vs linear pots and the arduino

Tags: pwm

I have noticed that when I used a log pot from a guitar amp I found, it gives janky results when using it in a motor PWM sketch, but if I use it in a fade sketch, it works. why does log pots give sketchy results when using them in a PWM control sketch, like when using the `map()` function?

Comment: what does `janky` mean? .... please define `sketchy results`  .... what is the difference between linear taper and log taper pots?

Comment: not quite for sure, except that I suspect the log outputs in log increments and the linear is more direct

Comment: janky is slang for like twist the pot, then the motor goes from 0 to 255 with no increments, non linear

Comment: http://www.resistorguide.com/potentiometer-taper/

Comment: Are you asking why it seems to work better when controlling an LED rather than a motor?

Comment: well no actually in my motor pwm sketch, I have a fade like function with step and speed and there is not jumpy action with this function but with a map() pwm only, the log pot is real messy, linear no issue

Comment: linear pot no issue

Comment: thanks for the link, that might explain why with a small turn, the log pot is non linear and jumps to the high end

Comment: @Jim Print out the values ranging from 0 to 255 coming from your pot and copy it into the question so that we can see better what you mean...

Answer (score 4):

There are two associated issues here that underly your problem.

Firstly, with a log pot, you get a period of very small changes in resistance followed by a period of massive changes:

[image]

(* a "commercial" log pot is how log pots are usually manufactured - two linear traces of different resistances back to back).

So when turning you get "not much ... not much ... not much ... lots ... even more ... full".

Now couple that with how a motor works. A motor has a "stall current", which is higher than the "run current" (especially the "unloaded" run current).  This is the minimum amount of current required to overcome the inertia of the motor and start it spinning. This is, in effect, a lower threshold on the PWM value that you need to exceed before the motor will begin moving (once it's started moving you can go a little below that threshold and it will still move).

With a linear pot it's easy to get to that threshold and stay around it, increasing slowly above it, etc.  However, as you can imagine looking at the curve of the log pot above, if the "flatter" area of the pot is below the stall current threshold of the motor, the motor will do nothing until you are well into the sharper up-turn of the curve.  The effect of this is you will go from "stopped" to "quite fast" in one jump. It's very very hard to get even close to the stall current threshold.

For instance, if your motor needs a minimum of 30% duty cycle to start it running, that's about a 160 degree turn on the log pot above, compared to just 70 degrees of a linear pot, and the rest of the log pot's PWM range is compressed into a tight space.

Comment: "Firstly, with a log pot, you get a period of very small changes in resistance followed by a period of massive changes:" yeah, that exactly what was happening, problem solved with a linear pot. forgot about the log study from my electronics

Comment: with the linear, even with the stall current, seems responsive throughout the range

Comment: There's a chance you may have an "antilog" pot (the pink line in the graph), which compresses most of the big changes to the left, then gives you not much after that. So you get a big jump at the beginning of the turn, then you see nothing else much for the rest of the turn.

Comment: the motor is very responive with a linear pot, and the serial monitor shows a clean transistion 0 - 255 using the analogWrite and map()

Comment: That is what I would expect.  Do a little experiment. See how far you have to turn the linear pot before the motor starts spinning, and look to see what the PWM value would be at that point. Try and do the same with the log pot.

Comment: the log sucks and I have ditched it. small turn gets a response with the linear, so changed the map() to compensate

Comment: Log pots are great for controlling things with a logarithmic response, such as audio volume, or LED brightness. And yes, they suck for anything (like a motor) that is more linear.